# Split the data into every 10 instances and concat with new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a DataFrame =

```
Lat    Lon     COG  Sog  status
16.23  23.92   20   14     1004
```

Length of the data set is 540x5

Now I need to split the data from row[0] to row[9] I.e 10x5 and store into a new DataFrame s. Next split the data from row[1] to row[10] I.e s1, next data from row[2] to row[11] i.e s2, upto 540 iteration. Then concatenate all the DataFrames and store into a new DataFrame.

Comment: What is the issue, which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

**Setup:**

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(20,4)),columns=list('ABCD'))
```

---

Using a list comprehension, we get the indices like below:

```
[(a,b) for a, b in zip(df.index,df.index[10:])]
#[(0, 10), (1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14), 
#(5, 15), (6, 16), (7, 17), (8, 18), (9, 19)]
```

Similarly just pass the indices under [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) then concat:

```
win = 10 #change the window as required 
final = pd.concat([df.iloc[a:b] for a, b in zip(df.index,df.index[win:])],sort=False)
print(final)
```

Comment: Thanks it works.                                                                                                                                Now, I need to concatenate column wise. row[0] to row[9] in block(i.e single row). row[1] to row[11] is second row(i.e second block) and so on...

Comment: @SudarshanaReddy if it works , kindly consider [`accepting`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer by clicking on the grey check mark

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data_lines = your_data.splitlines() #this create 540 line 5 columns
```

if you want to split line

```
split_data_line = data_lines[0]
```

if you print only status, try this code:

```
for line in data_lines
    print("status :{}".format(line.split()[-1]))
```

Comment: ' split_data_line = data_lines[0] ' split_data_line values change each use. If you not change research "append" method